# half controlable AC-DC converter

Tags: power-electronics, converter, ac-dc

We are studying power electronics, AC-DC converters. Our teacher drawn a circuit with its graph like below:
[image]

1. Id: inductor or load current.
2. Vs: voltage of source.
3. Vd: voltage of load or inductor.
4. Iq: thriystor gate current.
5. Id: current of load or inductor
6. T1: thyristor.

But I think there is an issue. There is inducive effect in the circuit but there is no phase difference between Vd and Id. There is but at end of the Vd-Id, not at alpha moment.

I think the graph should be like that:
[image]

Whose graph is right ?

Answer (score 0):

Your graph assumes all the current is "reactive" and no "real" power or work is done.

The original assumes some work is done and the R/L=Tau vs 2/f correlates to some meaningful power being drawn and heat dissipated in the load.

[Here's what I mean.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0Y2BMAWAnC1a0A4QEZIYQOxICsGAbGGdjEhsWSMiMcxMQKYC022AUNgQIg49YQTjDRAZikMIBYpERIyq8dipTEIAgkgqNBKtQIDVUMNgtgM2dPdSteAJ0kM44t8JvgcMXgBKXhoQIgzYcFgQVhQ4ZCwQiZDEvAAmILJYMu4YWbIZIKnsAGYAhgCuADYALrwA5l7ZjcQSibwA7l4eElJgCGKtHRl9A4xao2D8umMSCDAZZFjdOMOwUPRIUiAAKs4AlnV17K4AagD2NaVHvJXBsWHeUVC9MEJg0GCkUoSEcFJI2HwGD%204CGD2WcB8y0mnQeTUheTkvEhQgRoxCoxYJ0gpQAdmcikNMhl8sS5m1OghxuSFlgaZM5ltiBFhNoyHNhLlfHAAPoYHlgHlzJAEAUfSw83A8eLIFQAjDfOhSAU83m8qS8RnMFm9frsiDE6LYPkqiLEBBkVUEKSQVSIWCRKgYUXvWDGwW8ng8jVa5kSbAIPUctGhE2Cs0WyXs-SoMi6ARSbDEa1it0qtXezVgJkshBYfU4Fmh-miiOW10wd3i92SyUW6AIYhSAhgJCQuDUFS8KRYJ4VmgOQcrACSuNS5QAxtU8RP2AAdADOi%20oYHKAAlF9Uzsu17wgA)

[image]

Comment: I didn't understand why my graph is assuming all current is reactive. I added just phase difference between load voltage and load current at the alpha moment.

Comment: Phase depends on what R/L and 2pi f? What is Z(f)? You are just looking at L

Comment: if you mean impedance, Z = R + j*w*L or Z = sqrt(R^2 + X^2) X = 2*pi*f*L and phase difference is arctan(L*w/R) so R is not equal to zero. if R were zero, phi would be pi/2 but it is not, so there is real power.

Comment: Right so your 90 shift indicates R is very small.  Did you look at my simulation?  try 1H and see what happens to current and Power

Comment: But in my case R and L is not defined so we are trying to draw a general graph. When I increase the inductance, Vanode, real power and current is reducing.

Comment: so compute arctan over a range.  Or using my simulation note peak power (-ve) @ 100 uH and adjust to 50% peak VAR. What angle do you expect?  Note the VAR goes +ve due to X only

Comment: why should I compute arctan over a range ? If I select accurate values, I can obtain all arctan values, in the other words phi phase difference.

Comment: Did you follow my simulation and compute an answer to match?

Comment: When resistor is too big, real and reactive power is too small, real power is maximum. When inductor is too small, real power is maximum. When they are equal, reactive and real power is equal. So the phase difference can obtain all values. Also I am not sure of this circuit is same with mine. I guess I can't understand what you mean.

Comment: There is always a tradeoff between attenuation of AC and attenuation of DC (load regulation ~ Rs/load R) but choosing a low Q and lower f-3dB might achieve -12 dB 2 octaves down from 2f grid f but better with a 5th order RLC filter getting a notch at 2f rectified frequency while only losing 1% of DC, but takes effort, But in your explanation with Q=1 the apparent attenuation if the cutoff was 120 Hz is only 6 dB

Comment: If you add ripple and DC loss specs to question then I will +1

Comment: not need because we are trying to make a general formula. You can say A and B for them, for example.

Comment: It is difficult to generalize when there are Pd, and Joule constraints for switching with dynamic reactive loads and a wide range of ACR sensitivities that depend on load impedance and applied voltage. Try to constrain by defining these unknowns.

Comment: Thank you so much for your all helps. I guess I am not enough to understand this situation. Because there are a lot of variables.

Comment: The SCR will have a current gain of 200 to 1000 from Igt = Igh to I max rated  Gate and Holding current  to  Cathode current. The load must have an L/R time constant  much less than the cycle time to prevent power conduction voltage at near holding current cutoff.  or the line frequency to trigger properly and cutoff which depends on motor load too and there is a current phase shift from L/R vs f where back EMF and R changes with load from Series only to Rs+Rp//Xl